# How to prevent file editing on hosting?

Tags: wordpress, chmod, virus

The last week all my sites on last version of WordPress were cracked. I think, if I prevent editing of functions.php on hosting, it would be harder for viruses to distribute.

How to prevent file editing on hosting? What CHMOD I need to set?

The problem is that all files edited by the virus directly on server (system, the owner, do it itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent editing of functions.php (and all other theme files) by adding the following to your wp-config.php.

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true);
```

More details: https://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress#Disable_File_Editing

Messing around with the file permissions could break parts of your site, and I wouldn't recommend it. But if you really want to; run 
`chmod -R -w your/theme/path`, that will take write permissions away from everyone recursively.

If that breaks things; run `chmod -R u+w your/theme/path` to give write permissions back to the file owner.